# illustrator object scaling issue

Tags: vector, path, scaling, adobe-illustrator, distortion

I'm having an issue with a certain object, when I scale it down - anchor points appear to be moving about - and the logo (object) becomes distorted.

Please see attachment. You will see that the letters 'n' and 'a' are distorted. It's driving me crazy, any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this!

I saved the object as a SVG, then copied the SVG file over to the file that I wanted to use the logo on! Job done. Kind of impressed with myself too.